# Use DENSE_RANK() with left outer join

Tags: sql, rank

I'm using the above code to perform a left join on jira.releases table:

```
SELECT b.*,c.releasedate from digitalpfatforms.issues_braze b
Left join jira.releases c
On b.version_id=c.versionid
```

With this I get the following intended output:

| issueid | sprintid | sprintenddate | version_id | releasedate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1945 | 85 | 20/11/2021 | 45699 | 25/11/2021 |
| 1836 | 90 | 01/12/2021 | 54555 | 05/12/2021 |
| 1836 | 90 | 01/12/2021 | 54555 | 05/12/2021 |
| 2000 | 55 | 10/11/2021 | 56777 | 15/11/2021 |
| 2000 | 55 | 10/11/2021 | 56777 | 15/11/2021 |
| 2000 | 55 | 10/11/2021 | 56777 | 15/11/2021 |

Out of this output I need to calculate 2 dense_rank(). One over sprintenddate:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY b.sprintenddate DESC) AS "rank_sprint"
```

and the other over releasedate:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY c.releasedate DESC) AS "rank_release"
```

My intended output is the:

| issueid | sprintid | sprintenddate | version_id | releasedate | rank_sprint | rank_release |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1945 | 85 | 20/11/2021 | 45699 | 25/11/2021 | 2 | 2 |
| 1836 | 90 | 01/12/2021 | 54555 | 05/12/2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 1836 | 90 | 01/12/2021 | 54555 | 05/12/2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 2000 | 55 | 10/11/2021 | 56777 | 15/11/2021 | 3 | 3 |
| 2000 | 55 | 10/11/2021 | 56777 | 15/11/2021 | 3 | 3 |
| 2000 | 55 | 10/11/2021 | 56777 | 15/11/2021 | 3 | 3 |

Can anyone help me on how to put together the SQL query so that it perfoms a join and calculates the mentioned dense_rank?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you did all of the work already. Add the pieces together and it will work.

```
SELECT b.*,
c.releasedate,
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY b.sprintenddate DESC) AS "rank_sprint",
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY c.releasedate DESC) AS "rank_release"
from digitalpfatforms.issues_braze b
left join jira.releases c on b.version_id=c.versionid
```